# Write a function in Rust that returns a random normal deviate with specified mean and standard deviation

Tags: rust

I am experimenting with Rust and I am wondering how to write a simple function that returns a normal random deviate. I know generally how to do this, so my question is really more about global state and the way in which the rand_distr crate works. I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
fn main() {
 let x: f64 = rnorm(-2.0, 3.0); // returns a normal deviate with the given mean and standard deviation
 println!("{}", x);
}
```

This type of function is a very common pattern in simulation modeling as it is typically the case that one needs to generate many deviates, each with different parameters. Can a Rust expert fill in the definition of `rnorm` here?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work but raises some additional questions.

```
use rand::*;          // hard to figure out what is best here
use rand_distr::*;

fn rnorm(mu: f64, sigma: f64) -> f64 {
    let dst = Normal::new(mu, sigma).unwrap();
    return dst.sample(&mut thread_rng());
}

fn main() {
    let x: f64 = rnorm(-2.0, 3.0);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

So will this build and teardown the normal struct each call?

Comment: It will create and drop the `Normal` on each invocation, but `Normal` is just two floats, there are no allocations or anything involved.

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks. I assume the compiler will optimize away the abstraction here. Still, these calls often sit in the inner loops of critical paths and the `.unwrap()` bit makes me wonder if there is a cost here, when it needs to be zero relative to a hand-coded solution.

Comment: Personally, I'd leave the `unwrap` there unless you can prove it's significantly affecting performance. If you do happen to hit that case, check that `rnorm` is effectively inlined before using `unsafe { Option::unwrap_unchecked }` as a last resort.